# Same theme pictures( or paintings) merged

Tags: nouns, synonyms

Is there an english word (substantive) that refers to a type of picture or painting where there are merged lot of pieces of a same theme?

So far I found 'mural' and 'collage', but not sure if they are precise enough.

Attached picture of what I meant

https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0sr8.jpg

Comment: It is a collage, but I think you're right that there's a better word.  You could also call it a *collection* since it's (I assume) a set of characters from a videogame series.  Perhaps ***montage***?

Comment: Here's another example, of all the Simpsons characters. http://www.simpsoncrazy.com/content/characters/poster/full.jpg

Answer (score 3):

I think the best word for this is a ***montage***: see defn four below.

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/montage

> 1. the technique of combining in a single composition pictorial elements from various sources, as parts of different photographs or fragments of printing, either to give the illusion that the elements belonged together originally or to allow each element to retain its separate identity as a means of adding interest or meaning to the composition.
>      Compare collage (def 1).
> 2. photomontage.
> 3. Movies, Television.
>          juxtaposition or partial superimposition of several shots to form a single image.
>          a technique of film editing in which this is used to present an idea or set of interconnected ideas.
> 4. any combination of disparate elements that forms or is felt to form a unified whole, single image, etc.

You would call it, for example, "A montage of all the main characters from the Final Fantasy* videogame series"

*or whatever it is.

Answer (score 0):

How about a **tessellation** of pictures? Look at this as an example. ["Tessellation of pictures"](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=tessellation%20of%20pictures&safe=off&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjy4qrNqo3MAhWmHKYKHbCjBV0Q_AUIBygB&biw=1366&bih=631/%22Tessellation%20of%20pictures.%22%22).

*Tessellation* means an arrangement of shapes closely fitted together, especially of polygons in a repeated pattern without gaps or overlapping. I am not exactly sure if pictures with same theme can be substituted in place of polygons or shapes. (Also, I cannot see the picture which you have uploaded in my work place.)